# Obtain access to parent node from inside attrTween callback function (D3)

Tags: d3.js

I have a structure like this:

```
<svg class="pie" height="70" width="140">
    <g shift="0.14114767593868488" transform="translate(35,35)">
        <path class="arc" fill="#1f77b4" d="M-3.074456432660532,-29.842046137013963A30,30 0 0,1 20.028002120056104,22.335602321831978L10.014001060028052,11.167801160915989A15,15 0 0,0 -1.537228216330266,-14.921023068506981Z"></path>
        <path class="arc" fill="#aec7e8" d="M20.028002120056104,22.335602321831978A30,30 0 1,1 -3.074456432660514,-29.842046137013963L-1.537228216330257,-14.921023068506981A15,15 0 1,0 10.014001060028052,11.167801160915989Z"></path>
    </g>
    <g shift="2.805044461018128" transform="translate(105,35)">
        <path class="arc" fill="#1f77b4" d="M-3.074456432660532,-29.842046137013963A30,30 0 0,1 27.43141315203026,-12.145681227605914L13.71570657601513,-6.072840613802957A15,15 0 0,0 -1.537228216330266,-14.921023068506981Z"></path>
        <path class="arc" fill="#aec7e8" d="M27.43141315203026,-12.145681227605914A30,30 0 1,1 -3.074456432660514,-29.842046137013963L-1.537228216330257,-14.921023068506981A15,15 0 1,0 13.71570657601513,-6.072840613802957Z"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

You see, I have attached this 'shift' attribute to each 'g' element.

Now I have a this transition function (it's for rotating wheels). I want to access the value of the shift attribute of the parent 'g' element from inside the attrTween function (assigning it to that 'theShift' variable):

```
var wheelsData = [
    {
        arcs: [
            {startAngle: 0, endAngle: 0.4 * endAngle},
            {startAngle: 0.4 * endAngle, endAngle: endAngle}
        ],
        shift: Math.random() * fullAngle / 2
    },
    {
        arcs: [
            {startAngle: 0, endAngle: 0.2 * endAngle},
            {startAngle: 0.2 * endAngle, endAngle: endAngle}
        ],
        shift: Math.random() * fullAngle / 2
    }
];

var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(30).innerRadius(innerRadius);

svg.selectAll("g").remove();

var gBindings = svg.selectAll("g").data(wheelsData);
var gEnter = gBindings.enter();

gEnter.append("g")
    .attr("shift", function(d, i) {
        return d.shift;
    })
    .selectAll("path.arc")
        .data(function(d, i) { 
            return d.arcs;
        })
    .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "arc")
        .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
            return colors(i);
        })
        .transition().duration(5000)
        .attrTween("d", function (d) {
            var theShift = ???;
            return function (t) {
                ...
            };
        });
```

How to do that in D3? I have tried d3.select(this.parent), etc. But all failed (it doesn't return me the 'g' node apparently).

ANSWER:

Found it, using 'this':

```
.attrTween("d", function (d) {
  var pathElement = this;
  return function (t) {
    var shift = pathElement.parentNode.__data__.shift;
    ...
  };
});
```

Thanks in advance,
Raka

Comment: Since "shift" is not a standard attribute, you may want to consider using "data-shift" instead. "data-" attributes are standard in html5. Also, if you've already solved your own question, please post the solution as an answer instead of editing your question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Done, just posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, using 'this':

```
.attrTween("d", function (d) {
  var pathElement = this;
  return function (t) {
    var shift = pathElement.parentNode.__data__.shift;
    ...
  };
});
```

Comment: You should be able to accept your own answer after 2 days.